# Always on top Icon

Tags: icons, window, firefox

I am making a firefox addon that gives the user a menu, this menu lists all running processes and allows the user to pick which windows they want to keep on top. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The thing is though I want to give it a nice icon but I can't come up with one.

I thought of these stacks but they are just not good looking when they are 16x16 (i need sizes 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64). And it isnt really clear that its windows:

- [image] from iconfinder.com/icons/414066/add_layer_layers_stack_icon#size=16
- [image] from iconfinder.com/icons/252707/interface_popup_window_icon#size=16
- [image] from https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/569227/communication_internet_technology_window_windows_icon#size=16

  - This one is my favorite but it doesnt make clear that its a window always on top
- [image] from https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/340709/application_cascade_window_icon#size=16
- [image] from iconfinder.com/icons/294896/app_application_widget_window_icon#size=64

I like the color, but as seen in screenshot above, firefox toolbar buttons are gray so ill make a gray version of it for the toolbar. But I'll use the colored version of the icon everywhere else.

Does anyone have any good recommendations on how an icon for application should look which is focused on picking windows of process to be?

I have literally searched for days but cannot decide I need some guidance :(

A lot of the ones im finding are for "maximize window" which doesn't suit. Im ripping my hair out :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pin icon.

Thanks to Pinterest and the use of this icon in other apps (Microsoft Office, Google apps, etc) it is much more recognizable than stack icons.

Comment: Note that on Linux, a pin is often used to indicate a window that is present on all virtual desktops, rather than one that is always on top on the current desktop.